# Get the list of files inside a folder that have a date inside their name

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a folder with some files inside called in this way:

```
file_1_20200101235900
file_2_20200101235900
file_3_20200101235900
file_4_20200109999999
```

I would like to get a list containing all the files that have in their name a date in the format `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'`. so in this example I would like to get all the files except `file_4_20200109999999` because the date in it does not exist.

expected output:

`list =[file_1_20200101235900, file_2_20200101235900, file_3_20200101235900]`

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What part are you having trouble with? Listing files in a directory? Getting the relevant part of the filenames? Checking that the relevant part of a filename is a valid date? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, it's expected you try to solve a problem yourself, share your efforts with a clear description of where you're stuck and limit your question to that.

Comment: Use glob to iterate every file, and just pass in your paramaters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories) to iterate over the files and a custom function based on [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to validate the date.

Using a real date parser is the best option to ensure accounting for all subtleties to determine whether or not a date is valid.

```
def valid_date(date, fmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'):
    from datetime import datetime
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    
import os

path = '/path/to/your/files/'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if valid_date(f.rpartition('_')[-1])]
```

output:

```
['file_2_20200101235900', 'file_3_20200101235900', 'file_1_20200101235900']
```